# Changing the value of a next item in array

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I am trying to make a simple vue.js slider. I have a method that runs over every 10seconds to change the active item. I can't set the next item to be active.

```
this.items.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
    if(item.active == true)
    {
        console.log(arr[index+1].active);
        arr[index+1].active = true;
    }
});
```

The first line returns `false` or whatever the correct value of this is.

The second line returns `cannot read value active of undefined`.

This whole thing is in a Vue.js Method - is there more elegant way to do that?

Comment: Well the issue with this code above is if you set the item to active and looping over it, all the ones after it are also going to active.... And when you get to the last index, that is not going to be index+1. Why loop? Store the index is active and add one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the issue with this code above is if you set the item to active and looping over it, all the ones after it are also going to active.

And when you get to the last index, that is not going to be index+1. Which is undefined and hence the error you are getting.

Why loop? Store the index is active and add one

```
this.activeIndex = 0
```

and than in your next code

```
this.items[this.activeIndex].active = false
this.activeIndex++
if (this.activeIndex >= this.items.length) {
  this.activeIndex = 0
}
this.items[this.activeIndex].active = true
```

Comment: Do this but then also have a Vue computed property activeItem() { return this.items[this.activeIndex]; }

Answer (score 0):

This is throwing error on the last `index` because `arr[index+1].active` doesn't exist at that point. As, @epascarello mentioned, if you loop and update the way you're doing, once a `item.active= true` is found, every `item.active` post that is going to be set to `true`. You could change it to something like this instead:

```
this.items = this.items.map(function(item, index, arr) {
  if (index === 0)
    return item
  else
    return { ...item, active: arr[index-1]["active"] ? true : item.active }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple solution using `Array.prototype.findIndex()`:

```
let activeIndex = this.items.findIndex((element)=>element.active === true);
        this.items[activeIndex]['active'] = false;
    if(activeIndex == this.items.length-1){
        this.items[0]['active'] = true;
    } else {
        this.items[activeIndex + 1]['active'] = true;
    }
```

Comment: still going to throw the error when active item is last item in the array

Comment: Whoops - fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Can try this?

```
this.items.forEach(function(item, index, arr) {
        if(item.active == true)
        {
            if(arr.length !== (index+1) ){
                console.log(arr[index+1].active);
                arr[index+1].active = true;
            }

        }
    });
```